# How to configure Alt + Tab to switch between any instance of any application opened in any workspace on Ubuntu Focal Fossa 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, accessibility, alt-tab, ubuntu-20.04

I'm back to Ubuntu since it is back to Gnome. When I used other Gnome distros, I could switch between two Terminal windows using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> no matter the workspace they were.

Ubuntu 18.04 introduced a "window switcher" that showed every application in every workspace but you had to use another shortcut to switch between instances (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd>). I fixed it using a Gnome extension I can't find anymore. I don't even remember the name.

Is there a way in Focal Fossa (20.04) to achieve both functionalities (switch between any instance of any application in any workspace) with only two keys (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>)?

It is an accessibility issue for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as suggested in this answer — [shortcut keys - Force alt + tab to switch only on current workspace in GNOME shell - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464946/force-alt-tab-to-switch-only-on-current-workspace-in-gnome-shell/992675#992675) — the settings that might work for you are:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.window-switcher current-workspace-only false
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only false
```

The first line is required for 22.04, the second may be a legacy setting.

Answer (score 2):

The AlternateTab extension mentioned in [Almino's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1559953/399707) is no longer supported.

The solution to getting the same functionality working is described in [The future of AlternateTab, and why you need not worry](https://blogs.gnome.org/fmuellner/2018/10/11/the-future-of-alternatetab-and-why-you-need-not-worry/), which links to a [Gnome.org video](https://blogs.gnome.org/fmuellner/files/2017/09/how-not-to-use-alternate-tab.webm) showing the steps:

1. Open the control panel Keyboard Shortcuts
2. Within Keyboard shortcuts, search for the built in Window Switcher entry and enable it.

[image: Screenshot of Keyboard Shortcuts]

However, with respect to the AlternateTab extension, as the linked article states:

> In GNOME 3.30 this now works without the extension, which brings us to the extension’s future mentioned in the title. After the above explanation it shouldn’t come as a surprise that there is none — the extension will be retired for GNOME 3.32. If you are currently using it, please set up the built-in “Switch Windows” shortcut as outlined above, and enjoy having one less extension to worry about on updates…

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the extension I used in Ubuntu 18.04: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/15/alternatetab/

Comment: This extension is no longer supported. The solution to get it working is here: https://blogs.gnome.org/fmuellner/2018/10/11/the-future-of-alternatetab-and-why-you-need-not-worry/